# cron on centos creates only empty file

Tags: bash, cron

i know that this question has bin asked & answered a lot of times and i think i have read all of them :-( but still don't got it working :-(

OK, using CentOS release 8.2.2004 (Core) in root's cron i call a script

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/getSSHsessions.sh
```

the script just creates a file with some process listing

```
[root@myhost]# cat /home/getSSHsessions.sh

    #!/bin/bash
    /usr/bin/netstat -tnpa | /usr/bin/grep "VERBUNDEN.*sshd" > /mnt/ramdisk/sshsession.ls
```

but the output is just a empty file

```
[root@myhost]# ll /mnt/ramdisk/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root      0  5. Okt 19:33 sshsession.ls
```

I get crazy about that. Really don't know any more where to look.

Ah, yes, the script works fine run as user root on cmd-line. Then it creates the output as it should.

```
[root@myhost]# cat /home/getSSHsessions.sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/netstat -tnpa | /usr/bin/grep "VERBUNDEN.*sshd" > /mnt/ramdisk/sshsession.ls
[root@saprouter iteanova]# /home/getSSHsessions.sh
[root@myhost]# ll /mnt/ramdisk/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root     404  6. Okt 10:46 sshsession.ls
[root@myhost]# cat  /mnt/ramdisk/sshsession.ls
tcp        0      0 192.168.137.4:54782     192.168.137.2:80        VERBUNDEN   309654/sshd: myuser
tcp        0      0 192.168.137.4:22        95.208.219.123:33300    VERBUNDEN   309622/sshd: myuser
tcp        0      0 192.168.137.4:22        95.208.219.123:60744    VERBUNDEN   308085/sshd: myuser
tcp        0      0 192.168.137.4:22        35.203.68.135:36564     VERBUNDEN   310513/sshd: root [
```

Comment: Is it possible that root uses English and you have to grep for connected instead of verbunden?

Comment: still, in your getSSHsessions run the command without grep so you can see the output. this will make it easier to find the cause

Comment: Check your Linux mail account. Anything that leaks out of a cron job (like stderr) is mailed to your local user. Alternatively, add a redirect 2>myCron.log to the cron entry and check the file.

Comment: As is said in the post, when starting the script as root on cmdline, i got the output as i expect. I have updated the post qwith the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got the reason of the problem.

Someone pointed me to the language settings, which was right.

It seems that in CentOS the environment between a login-shell and a non-login shell are heavily different.

While root uses german as language in root-login-shell, it is set to english in root non-login shell (shell called from cron).

:-(

and same is the output of netstat.

OK, thanks for the hint.